# How to remotely compile and debug in Linux from within Visual Studio 2010

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2010, ubuntu

The source (ideally project) is to be compiled by gcc/g++ under Linux (Ubuntu). The source/project is to be opened/edited in Visual Studio environment. The output binary is to be debugged so that traces to viewed in Visual Studio 2010 and be ran in Linux step by step.
What is required to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work in VS 2010 but to debug something on Linux you should use GDB in remote mode. There is plugin fo GDB to VS but I'm not sure if it supports remote debuggin.

Here are some links that could be useful

- [Debug C++ code on Linux from Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/debug-c-code-on-linux-from-visual-studio.aspx)
- http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/linux/import/
- https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Connecting.html
- [Visual studio + remote gdb debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10145222/1387612)